# How to Ignore files in SONAR for a ReactJs application using JEST for testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sonarqube, code-coverage, jestjs

Ignore `index.js` files in sonar for a ReactJs application using `Jest` for testing.
My config in `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/index.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/*.{stories.js,demo.js}",
      "!**/build/**",
      "!**/mocks/**",
      "!**/coverage/**",
      "!**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  }
```

& the config in `sonar.properties`:

```
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.exclusions=**/*.spec.js,**/index.js,tests.webpack.js,webpack.config.babel.js,**/coverage/**/*.*
sonar.test=Sources/client/web-lure/src
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.js
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=Sources/client/coverage/lcov.info
```

In local, I do see `index.js` files be ignored But `SONAR` doesn't ignore these files.

Comment: how do you know that Sonar doesn't ignore them? BTW sonar config file should have name `sonar-project.properties`

Comment: because i can still see the files in issues under rules

Comment: then try to name config file correctly

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Coverage+Results+Import), you can use `sonar.coverage.exclusions` to disable coverage metrics for certain files.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why we need to specify exclusions in Sonar when we have already excluded those files in Jest? I don't see much point having to have exclusions in 2 places.